Macro Excel VBA that select all sheets if ends in "_T"
I wanna generate a macro that selects all the sheets that that ends in _T
I have only the following that allow me to select all the sheets
Sub SelectSheets()
Dim myArray() As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
j = 0
For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
If Sheets(i).Visible = True Then
ReDim Preserve myArray(j)
myArray(j) = i
j = j + 1
End If
Next i
Sheets(myArray).Select
End Sub


If you're not supposed to use (to know about) the Like operator and the sheet's visibility shouldn't be considered, you could use If Right(Sheets(i).Name, 2) = "_T" Then or add a couple of variables to get rid of the hard-coded 2. Note that this is a basic (beginner) code and there are many issues. If you share the big picture, you might receive useful information.

If you only need sheets whose names end in "_T" then this should work:
If Sheets(i).Visible And Sheets(i).Name like "*_T" Then
